# Calling Java Program from Oracle Trigger

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, triggers

I will try to be concise here. Actually I have a piece of code written in Java for sending sms to our customers.

We are using Oracle 10g as our database. All what I want here is that

"Whenever a row is inserted in a particular table, i want to create a trigger that can call my Java Program and passes couple of parameters to it e.g., Customer No, Invoice Id, Invoice amount etc."

I tried to find certain tutorials but mostly I am getting tutorials on creating java stored procedure to make certain changes in the database. I don't want that.

All I want is to have a way through which I can fire a trigger that calls my java program and pass some parameters to my java program. is it possible ?

Can anyone provide me with a code to write in an oracle trigger that just calls my program (lets say Test.java) with some parameters?? I'll be really greatful

Many Thanks

Comment: Once you have a SMS gateway this is quite easy to do in pure PL/SQL using built-in PL/SQL UTL_HTTP library. For instance @JefferyKemp has published his implementation for clicksend which I'm sure you could adapt to your own needs. [Find out more](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2016/08/send-sms-mms-and-voice-messages-from-oracle-plsql/)

Answer (score 2):

See [Calling Java Stored Procedure from Database Trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdev/calling-Java-from-database-triggers.html#GUID-5C498DEF-0348-484D-AA26-2A88EF348D5C)

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_sal ( 
> emp_id NUMBER,
>  old_sal NUMBER,
>  new_sal NUMBER
> )
> AS LANGUAGE JAVA
> NAME 'DBTrigger.logSal(int, float, float)';
> ```

Next, create the sal_audit table, as follows:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sal_audit (
>  empno NUMBER,
>  oldsal NUMBER,
>  newsal NUMBER
> );
> ```
>
> Finally, create the database trigger, which fires when a salary increase exceeds 20 percent:
>
> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sal_trig
> AFTER UPDATE OF salary ON employees
> FOR EACH ROW
> WHEN (new.salary > 1.2 * old.salary)
> CALL log_sal(:new.employee_id, :old.salary, :new.salary);
> ```

Define your code in `DBTrigger.logSal` method in this example

> ```
> public class DBTrigger{
>    public static void logSal (int empID, float oldSal, float newSal)
>                                                     throws SQLException{
> ```

Comment: you mean DBTrigger would be my javaClass name and logSal would be the method in my java program ?

Comment: I am getting this error after inserting row in the table

"class DBTrigger does not exist. Error during execution of trigger". Am I supposed to keep the class file at a particular location ?

Comment: i think i missed the loadjava step. however. now i am getting this error

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected a Java type at argument position 1 to which some Oracle value can be converted got something else

Comment: @Farhan I suggest you open a new question with your code